# Keycode for uppercase letters on soft keyboard in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am doing an experiment, where it requires a keyboard displaying both uppercase and lowercase letters **at the same time** (not display uppercase after pressing shift). Now I managed to display lowercase ones like a normal keyboard, using a sample project from SDK. This project uses code-label mapping in `xml` to define keyboard's layout like below:

```
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
    <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e"/>
    <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
    <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
    <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
    <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u"/>
    <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="i"/>
    <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="o"/>
    <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
```

Those are all for lowercase letters. The question is how to display uppercase ones. Are there codes-keyLabel value for uppercase, or is there any other way to include uppercase letters in the keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the code for both uppercase and lowercase of a letter is the same. When users press a letter key in a soft keyboard, the output will depend on the shift state of the keyboard view, which could be changed using `KeyboardView.setShifted(boolean)`.

Another thing is keys in a view should have the same shift state, thus it is not possible to display uppercase and lowercase for the same letter in one view at the same time. But it could be done in two different views, with one set as shifted and the other unshifted.

Comment: So, is there a way to display both down and upcase letters at the same time?

Comment: it could be done in two different views for one keyboard, with one unshifted and one shifted all the time; but not at the same view, because keys in a view should have same shift state. Yeah you remind me I should add this to my answer.

Comment: I see, but maybe if the keypress could be listened somehow before it's interpreted, you could add custom codes and intercept these codes and translate to the correct letter, or quickly change between shifted and non-shifted. I doubt such listener exists, though.

Comment: hmm. I think the listener you are talking about is `KeyboardOnActionLinstener`, but not sure how to implement custom codes. will try custom codes though, thanks!

Comment: Hey Yulong, did the method setShifted(boolean) work for you? I am using it passing "true" but the letters continue to be shown in lower case. Any tips?

Comment: @TiagoT Hey yeah it works. But as I said, it seems upper and lower cases cannot be displayed in the same layout at the same time; the 2 shift states could only be used in 2 different views.